# Spring AOP without XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop

I am trying to set up Spring AOP without any XML and wonder how to enable auto-proxying this way.

Defining an AutoProxyCreator-bean works, but isn't there an easier way?

This is what my @Configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class Context {
    @Bean
    public AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator annotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator() {
        return new AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator();
    };
    ...
}
```

All other beans are scanned in by `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring 3.0.x doesn't provide easy ways to replace XML namespace extensions (such as `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`) in `@Configuration`.

An upcoming Spring 3.1 will support special annotations for this purpose, such as [`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html).

Comment: Thanks, so I guess my solution is ok for the time being ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an aesthetically pleasing way to add the `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator`:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.register(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.class);
context.scan("com.myDomain");
context.refresh();
```